# Модуль requests не выдает json

Tags: python, requests

Модуль `requests` не хочет выдавать `json` при таком коде, пишу в `pycharm`, в чем может быть ошибка?

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

url = "https://bitality.cc/Home/GetSum?GiveName=Ethereum&GetName=Bitcoin&Sum=4.1895414&Direction=0"
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
print(response)
```

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что вам выдает вместо json?

Comment: Что-то выдает `{'giveSum': 4.1895414, 'getSum': '0.27923655'}`

Comment: вот, добавил скрин

Comment: Сделайте `response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)` (без `.json()`), потом `print(response.text)`, чтобы увидеть что приходит

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)